# variable expansion on string not working for python script argument

Tags: fish

I have a Python script that accepts an arg of `--ips` in a space separated manner. e.g. `--ips 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`. When I manually enter the IPS it works fine, and when I `set IPS "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"` and then use variable expansion with `script.py --ips $IPS` I get a different behavior and it doesn't work.

script.py

```
...
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Check TCP connections to a list of IPs.')
parser.add_argument("-i", "--ips", metavar="IPS", nargs="+", help="IP addresses to check, space separated")
args = parser.parse_args()

ips = args.ips

print(ips) # debug statement
...
```

Does not work using variable expansion: `set IPS "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"`:

```bash
$ script.py --ips $IPS
['8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4']
```

Works with manual expansion:

```bash
$ script.py --ips 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4']
```

If I use `(string split " " $IPS)` then it works but with an extra empty value:

```bash
$ script.py --ips (string split " " $IPS)
['3.211.248.172', '3.133.213.146', '52.15.105.130', '54.241.38.1', '54.177.51.127', '35.83.89.171', '50.18.17.93', '']
```

The variable appears to be a string:

```bash
$ echo $IPS
8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

EDIT: Maybe I need to understand strings and lists more in fish, researching now.

```
$ set --show IPS
$IPS: set in global scope, unexported, with 1 elements
$IPS[1]: |8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4|
```

Comment: Quote the variable: `--ips "$IPS"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try quoting it but it still resulted in a single element with both IPs in the same string e.g. `['8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4']`.

Answer (score 2):

K, the issue was quoting and two different cases here:

First, no quoting (works):

```bash
set IPS 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

set --show IPS
$IPS: set in global scope, unexported, with 2 elements
$IPS[1]: |8.8.8.8|
$IPS[2]: |8.8.4.4|
```

Second, with quoting (does not work):

```bash
set IPS "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"

set --show IPS
$IPS: set in global scope, unexported, with 1 elements
$IPS[1]: |8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4|
```

In both cases `echo $IPS` outputs a single line of IPs. I really needed the `set --show` command to show what was in the variable and not rely on variable expansion/substitution. I now see that I want the variable with each IP as an element, so that when variable expansion happens it will iterate correctly.

I understand more about what is happening now.

Comment: You seem to have left out the end of your answer.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting that, I just updated it.